# QCursor::pos(); renders wrong coordinates

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.12

I have a floating widget which should follow mouse.
Now I have another widget, which sometimes changes its position.

Before any other widgets resize, everything's ok. After the change my coordinates always go *astray* and the floating widget is shifted, it floats at a distance from the mouse. I've noticed that the shift is somehow connected to window size, it grows when the size is bigger.

I pass to widget mouse coordinates with `QCursor::pos();`, and I also tried sending `QPoint` from other background widgets, over which it should float with `mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)` and then `QPoint{ mapToGlobal( { event->pos() } )};`. These both render the same coordinates, and the same shift occurs.

E.g.
On a small window

- Floater's coordinates `QPoint(255,136)`
- Another widget's coordinates:
  `QPoint(0,0)`
- MapToGlobal from another widget: `QPoint(255,136)`

On a large window:

- Floater's coordinates  `QPoint(205,86)`
- Another widget's coordinates: `QPoint(0,0)`
- MapToGlobal from another widget: `QPoint(205,86)`

Can't grasp the problem, why it renders wrong coordinates.
The system is *Qt 5.12.3*. Any help will be appreciated.

---

UPD: The minimal reproducible example.

.h

```
class Area : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void moveArea();

};
```

.cpp

```
void moveArea::Area()
{
    move(QCursor::pos());
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  The problem is almost certainly with the way in which you use the value returned by `QCursor::pos` rather than function itself.

Comment: It's pretty simple. I'm using `move(QCursor::pos());` inside a widget. As far as I understand it has to attach left-top corner of the widget to the mouse. And it doesn't.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example added.

Comment: This is a code snippet, it is not a minimal reproducible example. For example it is not clear how you instantiate and show the instance of `Area`. And most important information of all is missing: does the instance have a parent widget....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QCursor::pos()` returns global (i.e. screen) coordinates but widget's position is measured in its parent's coordinate system if it has a parent. And is measured in global coordinates if and ONLY if the widget does not have any parent. So this code

```
void Area::moveArea()
{
   move(QCursor::pos());
}
```

will move the upper left corner of `Area` object to the mouse cursor position ONLY if `Area` object is a top-level window, i.e. when it has no parent. If it has parent (which I believe is your case), you need to map global coordinates to parent's coordinates by changing your code to `move(parentWidget()->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()));`.